# Force the .png extension on Mac Screenshots

Tags: macos, screenshot, file-extension, png

It's very easy to take a screenshot on the Mac with either Command-Shift-3 or Command-Shift-4, and they will be dumped on your desktop.  One major annoyance, however, is that the files created have no extension.

That may not be a problem on the Mac, but when you're trying to email these files to Windows users, they cause problems.

So the question is -- how can I force the Mac to save the screenshots with the .png extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They *do* have a `.png` file extension. Are you sure it's not just hidden?